# How to match start and end of a string?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepad++'s find & replace with a regular expression on the following sample:

```
 3   733xxxx (-1)
 3  1521xxxx (-1)
 3  1521xxxx (-1)
```

How can I keep only the following unmatched?

```
733xxxx
1521xxxx
1521xxxx
```

I've tried using the following expressions:

```
^(.* \(-1\)).*$
^(\(-1\))$
```

The first one matches everything, the second: nothing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this:

- Replace `"^ *\d+ +"` and `" *\(-1\)$"` (the quotes are for clarity) with empty string (2 steps)
- Replace `"^ *\d+ +(\d+).*$"` with `$1`

`\d` is a short-hand character class, which matches whatever `[[:digit:]]` matches (numeric digits). (Notepad++ uses Boost regex). From my testing, it seems that ***it can match Unicode numeric digits***, but I don't think it is going to matter much in your application.

The `^ *\d+ +` part will match the text before the numbers in the middle.

`*\(-1\)$` matches spaces and the `(-1)` at the end of the line.

For `^ *\d+ +(\d+).*$`, the regex will match the whole line, then we will retain only the part that we want, which is the numbers in the middle. The `()` (which are not escaped like in  `*\(-1\)$`) is a capturing group, which captures the text the sub-pattern matches. We don't care about the text following the captured number, so we use `.*` just to match everything.